# Dynamically populated NSPopUpButtonCell menu in an NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsoutlineview, nspopupbuttoncell

I’m working with an `NSOutlineView` which has two columns. My `dataSource` supplies the outline view with a tree of items of a custom class which represents file types (that is, you initialise it with a UTI). The first column is the display name of the file type (e.g., “Source code”, “Interface Builder NIB document”, etc.). The second column is an `NSPopUpButtonCell` which is supposed to allow the user to pick a handler for the given document type (think of Xcode’s “File Types” preference pane, and you’re pretty much there).

I can generate an `NSMenu` for a given item in the tree, populated with options based upon the Launch Services database entries for the UTI, complete with the relevant application icon and and so on. In fact, the menu itself works wonderfully, populated by way of `NSPopUpButtonCellWillPopUpNotification`.

The problem is, try as I might, the cell when the menu *isn’t* popped up always contains precisely one of two things: either an empty string, or the default text for the cell, the former if the result of `-handlerName` on the item (the attribute assigned to the column) is non-`nil`, the latter otherwise.

Moreover, I’m manually calling `-selectItem:` on the `NSPopUpButtonCell` instance, which just seems Wrong. In contrast, the left-hand column, which is just an `NSTextFieldCell`, everything just works (although granted, all it’s got to do is read the value from the item and present it).

(Disclaimer: I’m fairly new at Cocoa UI stuff; I know Objective-C, and lots of other programming languages, but I’ve not a huge amount of experience of building Mac OS X UIs, so be gentle).

Answer (score 1):

As I am also wrestling with outlineViews and popUpButtons, I'd dearly like to know the answer to this and many other questions. I'm afraid I can't really help you, but one thing did catch my eye:

> I can generate an NSMenu for a given item in the tree

Over the past tortuous weeks, I've learned one thing: when working with an NSTreeController and a datasource, always provide NSTreeNodes setting your real object (NSMenu in this case) as the representedObject.